# How to enter password that an external program asks from batch file

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

I'm writing a batch file to execute a program and do some requirements. After some steps, it asks me password.

Here is the .bat file I'm executing from command prompt;

```
C: 
cd "C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\GNUPT\GPG"
gpg -se -r "Someone <s.s@s.com>" "D:\20130328pcs0CONTAINER0035017310.txt"
```

So, after this step, that gpg program asks me my password;

[image]

Anyone knows how to write password here from batch file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the http://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manpage.en.html, did u try using:

```
--passphrase-fd n
```

> Read the passphrase from file descriptor n. If you use 0 for n, the
>   passphrase will be read from stdin.   This can only be used if only one
>   passphrase is supplied. Don't use this option if you can avoid it.

Not sure if something like this would work, set `n` to `1` to get the `passphrase` from the `sdtout`

maybe

```
gpg -se -r "Someone <s.s@s.com>" "D:\20130328pcs0CONTAINER0035017310.txt --passphrase-fd 1 & echo somePassword"
```

this makes one independent from the other so maybe it works. Please tell what happens

EDIT:

Mtok solved it with this:

```
gpg --trust-model always --passphrase some password --yes -se -r "<someone s@s.com>" "D:abc.txt"
```

Comment: I couldnt make it work. I also tried gpg -se -r --passphrase-fd 1 & echo somePassword "Someone <s.s@s.com>" "D:\20130328pcs0CONTAINER0035017310.txt" and some different combinations but not working. 

But this helped me to solve another problem. Thanks.

Comment: now I solved like this;  gpg --trust-model always --passphrase **some password**  --yes -se -r "<someone s@s.com>" "D:abc.txt"